# Scala implicit constructor

Tags: scala, implicit

Is it possible, in Scala, to instanciate an object without actually calling its name ?

In particular, I have :

```
val foo = Thing(
  Thingy(1,2,3),
  Thingy(4,5,6)
)
```

And I wonder if it would be possible to call it like that

```
val foo = Thing(
  (1,2,3),
  (4,5,6)
)
```

Comment: Use implicit as automagic conversion is generally a bad idea considering readability and maintenance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use implicit conversion from `Tuple3` to `Thingy`:

```
package example

case class Thingy(v1:Int, v2:Int, v3:Int)

object Thingy {
   implicit def tuple2Thingy(t: Tuple3[Int, Int, Int]) = Thingy(t._1, t._2, t._3)
   //add conversion in companion object
}
```

then you can use it like this:

```
import example.Thingy._

val foo = Thing(
    (1,2,3),
    (4,5,6)
)
```

If `Thingy` is vararg:

```
case class Thingy(v1:Int*)

object Thingy {
   implicit def tuple2ToThingy(t: Tuple2[Int, Int]) = Thingy(t._1, t._2)
   implicit def tuple3ToThingy(t: Tuple3[Int, Int, Int]) = Thingy(t._1, t._2, t._3)
   //etc until Tuple22
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I accepted it as an answer, but if you can edit to allow unknown-size Thingy, that would be perfect !

Comment: @Dranna You'd have to create implicit conversion for every tuple, from Tuple2 until Tuple22. It's boilerplate, but there is probably no other way.

Comment: It's easy to do it with shapeless: `implicit def make[Tuple](tuple: Tuple)(implicit toArray: shapeless.ops.tuple.ToArray.Aux[Tuple, Int, Array[Int]]): Thingy = Thingy(toArray(tuple): _*)`

Answer (score 4):

Here's another approach:

```
case class Thingy(a: Int, b: Int, c: Int)

case class Thing(x: Thingy, y: Thingy)

object Thing {
   def apply(t1: Tuple3[Int, Int, Int], t2: Tuple3[Int, Int, Int]): Thing =
     Thing(Thingy(t1._1, t1._2, t1._3), Thingy(t2._1, t2._2, t2._3))
}
```